# Are there any browser-plugins for optimizing JS/CSS files?

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications

I have an JavaScript application, which uses the ExtJS framework.

This brings two issues.

**CSS**

When using this framework, I end up with a huge CSS file, that contains hundrets of unused CSS deklarations. Also, since I'm also using some other libs, I got a few CSS files, which need consolidating. I see the list of sources in the dev-tools of my browser, but I can't automatically extract a list from it.

**JavaScript**

Since I am using the autoload mechanism of ExtJS4, I end up with exactly the sources I need, but those are multiple files. The problem is, the loading of the classes is so dynamic (I also generate some class names on the fly) that the sources list of the dev-toos is the only reliable way to know which files are really loaded, after clicking through the whole programm.

Sencha Cmd doesn't work at all for those problems.

**Is there any browser plugin, which gets me a list of all the sources (CSS/JS)?**

and

**Is there some browser plugin, that generates a CSS file, which only contains the used CSS declarations?**

Answer (score 1):

for css you can use this addon of firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Comment: does this _log_ the CSS that was used in _one run_ or does this just create a list of elements, that are currently in use?